# Mouse Over Images Disappearing When Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I inherited code that was written with Dreamweaver back in 2001 for our intranet site. The code used the famous MM_ Javascript functions to handle roll-over images for navigation (tabs across the top of the page). The intranet site was only used by IE for years, but a new manager wanted to make it work for Chrome. I am noticing in Chrome that the images disappear when clicked. Meaning the clicked image disappears and then all the images to the right slide over and as soon as they hit the mouse they also disappear.

I have junked the MM_ functions for simple "onmouse..." events but the same behavior happens in Chrome. Here is a sample of my code:

```
<SPAN> <A href="/demographics/CaseLookup" tabindex="-1"><IMG src="/site/images/tabs/Find_Case_on.gif"
onmouseup="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Find_Case_on.gif';" 
onmousedown="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Find_Case_on.gif';" 
onmouseover="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Find_Case_on.gif';" 
onmouseout="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Find_Case_on.gif';" border="0"></A><A href="/demographics/Demographics" tabindex="-1"><IMG src="/site/images/tabs/Case_Info_off.gif"
onmouseup="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Case_Info_on.gif';" 
onmousedown="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Case_Info_on.gif';" 
onmouseover="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Case_Info_over.gif';" 
onmouseout="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Case_Info_off.gif';" border="0"></A><A href="/demographics/CaseRelationships" tabindex="-1"><IMG src="/site/images/tabs/Case_Parties_off.gif"
onmouseup="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Case_Parties_on.gif';" 
onmousedown="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Case_Parties_on.gif';" 
onmouseover="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Case_Parties_over.gif';" 
onmouseout="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Case_Parties_off.gif';" border="0"></A><A href="/demographics/CaseMedicaid" tabindex="-1"><IMG src="/site/images/tabs/Medicaid_off.gif"
onmouseup="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Medicaid_on.gif';" 
onmousedown="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Medicaid_on.gif';" 
onmouseover="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Medicaid_over.gif';" 
onmouseout="this.src='/site/images/tabs/Medicaid_off.gif';" border="0"></A></SPAN>
```

I am not able to use cssSprites because each tab is displayed individually per user security (if the user can't get to a page, they don't see the tab image - if they try to get to the page directly, they are redirected to home). Could it be that when the user navigates away from the page, the onmouseover still tries to fire, but the image is no longer available? The odd thing is that this code works as desired on IE and Firefox.

Any suggestions? -- Einy

Comment: JEEZ THAT'S UGLY O_o! You can always use a `script` rather than doing everything inline. Can you please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Did you copy-pasted html4 ? <SPAN> <A <IMG  ?? You're doing a newsletter?